# filter query result by user

Tags: solr, solr4

I want to restrict the returned results to be only the documents that were created by the user.
I then load to the index the createdBy attribute and set it to index false,stored="true"

```
<field name="CreatedBy" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

then in the I want to filter by "CreatedBy" so I use the dashboard, check edismax and add 
I check edismax and add CreatedBy:user1 to the qf field.

the result query is

```
http://....:8983/solr/vault/select?q=*%3A*&defType=edismax&qf=CreatedBy%3Auser1
```

Nothing is filtered. all rows returned.
What was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fq=CreatedBy:user1
```

*qf* stands for [Query Fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29), while *fq* stands for [Filter Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq)